# Dividing time with timespan

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timespan

Hey guys I have uploaded an image with this post. In the image there are four time stamps. The first and last are dynamic as they keep changing. I want the middle two to also change with difference of the first and four. For example if Timer 1 = 2 and Timer 4 = 5, then Timer 2 and 3 should be respectively 3 and 4. There should be equal distribution with the 4 lines.

Now I am using TimeSpan to display in the format {HH:MM} and I cannot divide the timestamp with an integer as it does not allow me to. So what choice do I have here?

```
public TimeSpan HoursMinutes_01;
public double totalMinutes_01;
private string result_01;

public TimeSpan HoursMinutes_02;
public double totalMinutes_02;
private string result_02;

void Start()
{
      //For First Timer
            HoursMinutes_01 = new TimeSpan (1, 0, 0);
            totalMinutes = HoursMinutes_01 .TotalMinutes;
            result = string.Format ("{0:D2}:{1:D2}", HoursMinutes_01.Hours, HoursMinutes_01.Minutes);

     //For Second Timer
            HoursMinutes_02 = new TimeSpan (4, 0, 0);
            totalMinutes = HoursMinutes_02 .TotalMinutes;
            result = string.Format ("{0:D2}:{1:D2}", HoursMinutes_02.Hours, HoursMinutes_02.Minutes);
}
```

[TimeDifference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFmY3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For displaying time in {HH:MM} format use this:

```
TimeSpan oneAndHalfHour = new TimeSpan(1, 30, 0);
Debug.Log(string.Format("You were out of game for: {00} hours and {1:00} minutes", oneAndHalfHour.Hours, oneAndHalfHour.Minutes));
```

For dynamically found 2nd and 3rd time use this.

```
TimeSpan firstTime = new TimeSpan(1, 30, 0); // 1.5 hour
TimeSpan secondTime = new TimeSpan(); // Should be 2 hour 
TimeSpan thirdTime = new TimeSpan(); // Should be 2.5 hour
TimeSpan fourthTime = new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0); // 3 Hour

TimeSpan difference = fourthTime - firstTime;
// There are 3 element between 1st and 4th time, should include 1st one too
// This variable will give us interval between every time
int differenceInMinutes = (int)(difference.TotalMinutes / 3);

secondTime = firstTime.Add(new TimeSpan(0, differenceInMinutes, 0));
thirdTime = secondTime.Add(new TimeSpan(0, differenceInMinutes, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Going by minutes as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66280487/7111561) is actually quite expensive.

You could/should rather go down to the most basic value with is the `Ticks`:

```
var firstTime = new TimeSpan(1, 30, 0);
var fourthTime = new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0);

var difference = fourthTime.Ticks - firstTime.Ticks;
var step = difference / 3;

var secondTime = new TimeSpan(firstTime.Ticks + step);
var thirdTime = new TimeSpan (secondTime.Ticks + step);
```

This is more efficient for multiple reasons:

- `.Ticks` simply returns the stored ticks without any extra calculations
- The constructor taking ticks simply stores these ticks without any extra calculations
- we use an int division which is also faster than a double division
- we don't create instances of `TimeSpan` where we don't need to but calculate with the ticks (`long`) directly

And to generalize it

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns an array of all time steps between from and to (including from and to)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="from">the first time</param>
/// <param name="to">the last time</param>
/// <param name="stepCount">How many steps to insert between first and last time</param>
public TimeSpan[] GetInBetweenTimes(TimeSpan from, TimeSpan to, int stepCount)
{
    if(stepCount <= 0)
    {
        return new[]{from, to};
    }

    var times = new List<TimeSpan>{from};

    var difference = to.Ticks - from.Ticks;
    var ticksStepDelta = difference / (stepCount+1);
    if(ticksStepDelta == 0)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Difference between from and to is too small for the given stepCount!");
        return return new[]{from, to};
    }

    var currentStep = from.Ticks;
    for(i = 0; i < stepCount; i++)
    {
        currentStep += ticksStepDelta;
        times.Add(currentStep);
    }

    times.Add(to);
  
    return times.ToArray();
}
```

---

And for the `string` rather simply use

```
var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(1,30,0);
var stringValue = someTimeSpan.ToString("hh\:mm");
```

> 01:30

Comment: Thanks for proposing more optimized solution. But can I ask why it is much more expensive? Yes your solution will run faster a bit but from [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/e5003a04d5193095.html), it doesn't look so different.

Comment: @SeLeCtRa the ticks is the underlying value which is stored. Everything else are properties that have to be recalculated every time you access them => Accessing the ticks is much more efficient. And in the other direction also the constructor taking ticks is much more efficient since it just takes and stores the given ticks again. Using any other constructor basically takes the given hour,minutes,seconds e.g. and recalculates it into ticks in order to store it => Again going by ticks is much more efficient

Comment: I aggree with you, but I just said, performance wise, it is almost unnoticable. We are just dealing with small double values here, if it would have been array/List/Dictionary, your code would be far more better. But in this case, performance is unnoticable. But thanks for another point of view

Comment: @SeLeCtRa Performance wise this is more efficient ;) now if it will be *noticable* / *matter* always depends on how often you do it of course ;)